# Z-index in IE: li element disappeared when over on it

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, z-index

In JS code I declare that when over on the LI element in the vertical Menu all the `li` elements get style: `z-index:5` except the current over `li` element and `li` element with `class="selected"` that the style is: `z-index: 10`.
In chrome, FF it works well but in IE when I over the `li` element of the menu it disappeared.

The follow is the JS code:

```
var mainMenu_li = document.getElementById('mainMenu').getElementsByTagName('li');

for(i = 0; i < mainMenu_li.length; i++)
    if(mainMenu_li[i].className != "selected")
        mainMenu_li[i].style.zIndex = '5';

$('#' + curObjID).parent().css('z-index','10');
```

How can you help me?

Comment: Can't help without seeing your HTML. Also, see: http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/01/Explorer_z_index_bug.html

Comment: Sorry I forgot write the link...http://yagen.org

Comment: I didn't declare z-index: 0....

Answer (score 0):

First of all read this series of articles: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index

If you trying to use z-index in IE7 - it have problems with it - try to build menu based on "Stacking without z-index". For example - without hover `position:static`, with hover `position:relative`.

Also try to set without hover `position:relative;` (without z-index) and on hover `position:relative;z-index:2`

It will better if you put your styles to classes and manipulate with jquery through classes: `addClass('class')` and `removeClass('class')`